# How do I safely parse a string to a slog level?

Tags: go, logging

I'm using the package **log/slog** and want to parse a given string to a valid `slog.Level`. I started with the following

```
func doSomething() {
    levelAsString := "this can be anything"

    var level slog.Level

    switch levelAsString {
    case "Debug":
        level = slog.LevelDebug
    case "Info":
        level = slog.LevelInfo
    case "Warn":
        level = slog.LevelWarn
    case "Error":
        level = slog.LevelError
    default:
        // invalid log level, handle error
    }

    // valid log level, move on ...
}
```

I couldn't find a "tryParse" function. Do you have any ideas how to parse a given string? I'm looking for something like

`level, parseError := slog.ParseLevel("this can be anything")`

Comment: What you did works, fast and safe. An alternative would be to list valid string levels in a map, mapping to the appropriate `slog.Level` values. Then the parsing would be a map indexing.

Answer (score 0):

Go doesn't support enums the same way other languages do. Instead, you can define a new type, e.g. `slog.Level`, and declare a few values as special constants and name them in a way that feels like enumerations (as slog has done for you here), but at the end of the day `slog.Level` is an int and so is `slog.LevelDebug` and so is `7`. Go will say that 7 is a valid `slog.Level` even though there isn't a constant variable that holds 7.

You're defining the functionality related to converting a string to an enum value. You can pick the strings, you can decide how to respond to unexpected strings (assume a default? throw an error? ask the user again?), you could make it case sensitive, you could leave out an entire level if you think having a Debug level is stupid (don't do that, but you get the point I hope). Go does not have a standardized way to do any of this.

If you're working on a library, the community might benefit from putting the conversion in a function and having a second function for converting the other direction but I would think hard about if you actually NEED this or if you're just making them jump through hoops to use your enum instead of slog's. It's hard to recommend what you should do because this is *your* code and it's subjective based on your goals.

Answer (score 0):

could be done this way

```
func ParseLevel(s string) (slog.Level, error) {
    var level slog.Level
    var err = level.UnmarshalText([]byte(s))
    return level, err
}

func doSomething() {
    levelAsString := "this can be anything"

    level, err := ParseLevel(levelAsString)
    if err == nil {
        // valid log level, move on ...
    } else {
        // invalid log level, handle error
    }

}
```